# Appium automation testing How to use Android native Camera

Tags: ruby, rspec, appium

I want to write a simple Automated test that launches and takes a picture from Androids's native Camera. I can launch the Camera but cant take the picture.

Iv tried looking in Appium Inspector to get the :xpath for the button that takes the pic so that i can do a ".click" on it, But its not there.

Im new to Appium, I haven't been able to find any info online. I dont know even if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some People have said `press_keycode 27` should work but it doesn't for me.

I've done a quick fix by using the Co-ordinates of the 'take image' Button and then tapping it e.g.

```
Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 1770, y: 540).perform
```

But this is only valid on a specific Device i.e. my Samsung s4